# Parameter input works, but pipe doesn't

Tags: shell

I tried to create a shell script, which sum the given numbers. If there is no given parameter, then it tries to read the pipe output, but I get an error.

```
#!/bin/sh

sum=0

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
  while read data
  do
    sum=`expr $sum + $data`
  done
else
  for ((  i = 1 ;  i <= $#;  i++  ))
  do
    sum=`expr $sum + ${!i}`
  done
fi

echo $sum
```

This works: `sum 10 12 13`
But this one doesn't: `echo 10 12 13| sum`

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You're using `bash`, right? Because your for loop isn't an `sh` loop.

Comment: sorry, I'm beginner. I don't really understand it

Comment: All right, let's assume you're using `bash` then. It doesn't work because in the second case, the variable `data` contains `10 12 13`...

Comment: Then could you please help me, how to loop through the data elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go (assuming `bash`, not `sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

sum=0

if (( $# == 0 )); then
  # Read line by line
  # But each line might consist of separate numbers to be added
  # So read each line as an array!
  while read -a data; do
    # Now data is an array... but if empty, continue
    (( ${#data[@]} )) || continue
    # Convert this array into a string s, with elements separated by a +
    printf -v s "%s+" ${data[@]}
    # Append 0 to s (observe that s ended with a +)
    s="${s}0"
    # Add these numbers to sum
    (( sum += s ))
  done
else
    # If elements come from argument line, do the same!
    printf -v s "%s+" $@
    # Append 0 to s (observe that s ended with a +)
    s="${s}0"
    # Add these numbers to obtain sum
    (( sum = s ))
fi

echo $sum
```

You can invoke it thus:

```
$ echo 10 12 13 | ./sum
35
$ ./sum 10 12 13
35
$ # With several lines and possibly empty lines:
$ { echo 10 12 13; echo; echo 42 22; } | ./sum
99
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit.** You might also be interested in learning cool stuff about `IFS`. I've noticed that people tend to confuse `@` and `*` in `bash`. If you don't know what I'm talking about, then you should use `@` instead of `*`, also for array subscripts! In the `bash` manual, you'll find that when double quoted, `$*` (or `${array[*]}`) expands to all the elements of the array **separated by the value of the `IFS`**. This can be useful in our case:

```
#!/bin/bash

sum=0

if (( $# == 0 )); then
  # Read line by line
  # But each line might consist of separate numbers to be added
  # So read each line as an array!
  while read -a data; do
    # Now data is an array... but if empty, continue
    (( ${#data[@]} )) || continue
    # Setting IFS=+ (just for the sum) will yield exactly what I want!
    IFS=+ sum=$(( sum + ${data[*]} ))
  done
else
    # If elements come from argument line, do the same!
    # Setting IFS=+ (just for the sum) will yield exactly what I want!
    IFS=+ sum=$(( $* ))
fi

echo $sum
```

Gniourf now exits from teacher mode. `:-)`

Comment: Excuse me sir, but I have to use the `#!/bin/sh` stuff at the beginning. Thank you for helping me, but how can I use `while read -a data` in sh? If I replace my `while read data` to `while read -a data`, then I get no error message, but the result is the first number ( 10 )

Comment: @DonPavilon You need to use `${data[@]}` to obtain an array (try `echo "${data[@]}"` to print out the array). Why do you need to use `#!/bin/sh` if you're using `bash` commands?

Comment: Now I understand it all. Thank you for your help sir!